# How do I find the global position of a root node in an armature?

Tags: animation, blender, collada, assimp

I have a root node with its head (very start of the armature) roughly located globally at 0, 0, -1.5 and its tail at 0, 0, 0 according to the cursor.

When in edit mode however, I see that the head is at 0, 0, -0.108 and its tail is at 0, 0, 1.374.

Once more, when I export the model as a Collada and import using Assimp, I see that the position of the root node is at 0, 0, -0.108. I don't have enough information to derive its actual position, although I suppose I could use the position of its child node, but that position is relative.

How do I obtain the global position of the head on the root node using the information I have?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be able to get this information from the offset matrix of the current bone in combination with the transformation stored in your root node. But of corse you will only get the root transformation for your local aiScene.